# Background-size: cover property with Windows Phone browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, windows-phone

I'm trying to use the `background-size: cover` property. It works everywhere but .. on windows phone ! (I tried with a HTC 8X)

```
body.menu{
    background: url('[my_picture_link]') no-repeat top center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='[my_picture_link]', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='[my_picture_link]', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Although this maybe buggy. Here is a good article about covers: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/